# Measure Point Along a Line

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

Looking to find Distance along a line(road) by a user input(Mouse Click). Here is my python code TESTED and works

def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):

 mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

 df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

 pointGeom = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(x, y), mxd.activeDataFrame.spatialReference)

 road_layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "narr", df)[0]

 arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(road_layer, "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", pointGeom, "50 FEET")

 arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

 output_layer = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(road_layer, arcpy.Geometry())

 dist_along_road = output_layer[0].measureOnLine(pointGeom) 

 pythonaddins.MessageBox(dist_along_road / 5280, "Address", 1)

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: MeasureOnLine function can not be called against the layer

Comment: is Measures enabled for your feature class?

Comment: I need some sample code for the "measureOnLine" function

Comment: These code might be closer. The error now is "object has no attribute 'measureOnLine'"

Comment: Take a look at [Defining Feature Class Properties](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/feature-classes/defining-feature-class-properties.htm#GUID-8EE6F702-D419-4624-B28E-01FF08233871) - Measures needs to be enabled to use the measures functions

Answer (score 2):

First of all does your `output_layer` actually contain any geometries? I ask this as your select by location is set to **INTERSECT**. No one can ever click on a line, so may be change that to *closest* or create a buffer around your point and use that as the selecting geometry.

Secondly *measureOnLine* is a method for [Polyline](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/polyline.htm) geometry, your code is trying to run that on your cursor `cursorRoad`, you need to get the row from the cursor then the geometry. Suggest you read [this page](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/reading-geometries.htm) and study the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help Hornbydd.. I have posted the working code... Now I can convert this arcpy to pyQGIS